# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1072: the Oracle Client library version is unsupported using Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to use Python 3.7 via Intellij Ultimate 2020.1 to run simple scripts on SQL Developer 19.4.

I have downloaded and installed the cx_Oracle python library, downloaded
Oracle Instant Client Basic Package and SQL*Plus package and set them in the same folder.

Here is my code which produces the error with certain specific bits left out for security reasons:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pyperclip

lib_dir=r"<PATH>\instantclient_19_9"
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir)

user=input("Please enter your username for the DB: ")
input("Please copy the password for <DB> Now, press enter here when complete") #Need to copy the password into clipboard so pyperclip can paste it in the password field for security

#Start the connection
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, pyperclip.paste(), "<HOST ADDRESS>") #Username,password,hostaddress

# Obtain a cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Execute the query
sql = """<SQL QUERY>"""
cursor.execute(sql)

# Loop over the result set and save as a list
output=[]
for row in cursor:
    output=output.append(row)

print(output)

#Close the connection
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

When i run this I get the following error:

*File "C:/Users/F694236/IdeaProjects/untitled1/.idea/5030testv0.py", line 5, in 
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1072: the Oracle Client library version is unsupported*

I have scoured the installation guides but cannot see any solution to this problem that has worked

**UPDATE**:
After running the environment variable with DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL to 64 it gives this output:

```
ODPI [09396] 2020-11-27 09:52:28.968: load in parameter directory 
ODPI [09396] 2020-11-27 09:52:28.968: load in dir \\<PATH>\F694236\instantclient_19_9 
ODPI [09396] 2020-11-27 09:52:28.968: load with name \\<PATH>\F694236\instantclient_19_9/oci.dll
ODPI [09396] 2020-11-27 09:52:28.998: load by OS successful
ODPI [09396] 2020-11-27 09:52:28.998: validating loaded library
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:<>\DEV\Tools\IntelliJUltimate\2020.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\<>\DEV\Tools\IntelliJUltimate\2020.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/F694236/IdeaProjects/untitled1/.idea/5030testv0.py", line 5, in <module>
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1072: the Oracle Client library version is unsupported
```

Comment: Do have the required VS Redistributable installed? See the instant client download page.

Comment: What OS are you using? You will get that error with Windows XP, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Well my first questions would be: have you configured the Environment Variables?

If yes it might be that Intellij finds another version of oci.dll in your Path, until the end of the Path is reached.

My suggestion would be to check your PATH environment variable and check each directory in your PATH for any oci.dll which might be there.

Maybe the following Link will help you out as well:
https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#initialization

In the meantime, if the Oracle Client has been installed accordingly, you can try as workaround, the following thing:

```
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(hostname, port_number, sid)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(SCHEMA_NAME, SCHEMA_PASSWORD, dsn)
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

I know that the above workaround is not really security-friendly, but at least you can try and see if the problem is related to the Oracle Client or you need to search for the problem somewhere else.

Comment: With `cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir)` in cx_Oracle 8, you don't need to set PATH on Windows.

Comment: Hi,Im not entirely sure what you mean by Environment variables, where exactly would I have configured those? I'm quite new to IntelliJ as i am more used to using Jupyter

Comment: Well as Christopher Jones said, when uxing cx_oracle 8, you no longer require to set PATH on Windows. 
But nevertheless, to set the Environment Variables, please follow:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFUEU_8.0.0/op_grc_installation/t_camphor_setting_environment_variables_ora.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Oracle Instant Client is the same 32- or 64-bitness as your Python executable. If this doesn't solve it, then before starting Python, set the environment variable DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL to 64 and update your question with what it shows - it will be the search path used to load the Oracle Client libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Oracle Instant Client version I was using was too old.  I was using the version of Instant Client that supported Windows 7, but I was running on Windows 10.  It must not be compatible with what Python 3.7 was using.  Using the latest version of Oracle Instant Client dlls with my Python 3.7 application made it work.

I only needed to add oci.dll and oraociei.dll into the same folder where I had my .py program.  I used import cx_Oracle and my call to cx_Oracle.connect was successful.